# How can I increase php variable's value every time form is submitted?

Tags: php, forms

I have a variable in php, called `$number`, and I have a submit button:

`<form method="get"><button type="submit" value="<?php echo $number; ?> name="next">Next</button></form>`.

What I'd like to achieve, is to increase the value of that variable, by 10 for example, every time the form is submitted.

First this is how I'd tried it:

```
if(isset($_GET['next'])){
$number+=10;
}
```

But this code only increases its value once.

I've tried several methods that are not really worth mentioning, but none of them worked unfortunately.

Comment: Every time the form is submitted per user, or any user? Assuming the latter, you need to store the number in a data store, whether that's a file on the server, a database, or something else.

Comment: pass last value in url and increment it with 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['next'])){
   $_SESSION['number'] += 10;
}
?>    
<form method="POST">
  <button type="submit" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['number']; ?>" name="next">
    Next
  </button>
</form>
```

POST the form, and use Sessions to ensure you still have the previous variable available after the reload.

**Useful reading:**

**PHP Session:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

**PHP Session Start:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

**According to Wikipedia:**

> GET requests a representation of the specified resource. Note that GET
>   should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as
>   using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this
>   is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which
>   should not need to consider the side effects that a request should
>   cause.

and

> POST submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the
>   identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request.
>   This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of
>   existing resources or both.

Comment: Why change to POST?

Comment: As you are POSTing data, not GETing data.  You are submitting data to be used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get

Comment: But it's incorrect to use GET in this instance whether it would work or not.

Comment: But it's still incorrect and bad practice, so how about we encourage good practice yeah?

Comment: "POST submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form)" ... I'm not the one who decides these things.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['next'])){ ... } <--- Data being processed.

Comment: Done with my pedantry :)